# Unhover animation css only

Tags: html, css

I wrote an animation for a button. When I hover in its parents, It will be slide from right to left by a little bit. I want to write an animation that when I leave the mouse on "product-list-item", it will have a delay and disappear slow down like when I hover the mouse. But I don't know how to write that.

Please help me!

codepen: 
https://codepen.io/quantranbber/pen/WNbezQb

```html
<div class="product-list-item">
  <div class="add-to-cart">
    <button class="btn">hello</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.product-list-item {
        position: relative;
        width: 25%;
        float: left;
        height: 320px;
        border: 1px solid rgb(228, 225, 225);
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 15px;
    }
    .product-list-item:hover {
        box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px 5px rgb(231, 231, 231);
    }
    .product-list-item:hover .add-to-cart {
        animation-delay: 2s;
        animation: slideInRight 0.2s ease-in-out 0s forwards;
    display: block;
    }
    @keyframes slideInRight {
        from {
      transform: none;
      right: 0;
        }
        to {
      right: 15px;
        }
    }
    .add-to-cart {
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
    bottom: 15px;
    }

    .add-to-cart:after {
    content: '';
    width: 0px;
        position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s; 
    }
    .add-to-cart>.btn {
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        background-color: red;
    }
```

Comment: Just some food for thought, how can something animate if you set the display prop to none :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you may want is actually a CSS transition: https://codepen.io/aprouja1/pen/GRgKdjZ

I adjusted the button so that the `opacity` changes and there is a `transform:translateX`instead of the animation

```css
.product-list-item {
  position: relative;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  height: 320px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(228, 225, 225);
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.product-list-item:hover {
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px 5px rgb(231, 231, 231);
}

.product-list-item:hover .add-to-cart {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(-15px);
}

.add-to-cart {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.add-to-cart:after {
  content: '';
  width: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.add-to-cart>.btn {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-list-item">
  <div class="add-to-cart">
    <button class="btn">add-to-cart</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Literally 2 seconds too slow. I was going to offer a similar solution. But don't post link only answers, for many reasons, mainly link rot. Use the snippet

Comment: Np, just a suggestion, be careful of being generous with `transition: all` since you are only targeting 2 properties. It can also be written as: `transition: transform 0.5s, opacity 0.3s;`